# tomcat fails to find attachment in jasper ws response

Tags: soap, tomcat6, jasperserver, tcpmon

I am experiencing an issue with a web application which connects to a remotely hosted jasperserver  (both tomcat hosted) , where the SOAP response is not identified by the web application saying "Attachment not present!".

I tried isolating the issue with tcpmon and following are my observations

1.) Jasperserver responds with the correct Jasperprint content type (Octetstream for the attachment is present) - 
I found few answers which mentioned that there's some limitation with jasperserver's attachment size and a permission issue with the attachments folder within the jasperserver. But it seems not the issue in this case.
 
2.)SOAP response is correctly received in a tcpmon which I was running in the client side.So I guess i could safely rule out any content type related issue over the network.

However, it seems that even though the response is arriving correctly to the client tomcat, either the tomcat or the application has an issue with identifying the attachment.

I haven't done any updates or changes in the jasperserver, ireport client or axis libraries also.

I would much appreciate if somebody can point me where to check next and any possible root causes.